# Adding a mouseListener/ mouseEvent to each object in an objects list

Tags: java, object, canvas, graphics, mouselistener

I am trying to add a mouselistener to each object that is in an objects list. I am rendering a frame as well as multiple objects, using canvas and graphics g.

This is my main class: this renders the frame as well as the objects. This all works well and there is no problem here.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Proj2 extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    private final int[][] Init_board = 
          {{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
           {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
           {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
           {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
           {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
           {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
           {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
           {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}};

    private final int[][] new_Game = 
          {{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
          {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
          {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4}};

    public static final int WIDTH = 640;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 640;
    private final int initPieces = 8;

   private Thread thread;
  private boolean running = false;

    private Board board;
    private GameHandler handler;    

    public Proj2(){

        handler = new GameHandler();
        new Window(WIDTH,HEIGHT,"Checkers",this);
        board = new Board(WIDTH,HEIGHT,Init_board);

         for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){

              handler.newObject(new Player(j * (640 / initPieces),i * (640 /
              initPieces),initPieces,ID.playerOne,new_Game[i][j],handler));

             }
         }
```

This is where I'm not sure if I am doing it right. I have created the objects above, and render them to the frame. Then I try to add a mouslistener to each object so that they can each have their own MouseEvent. This is still in my main class.

```
for(int i = 0; i < handler.gameObjects.size(); i++){

    GameObjects temp = handler.gameObjects.get(i);

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseInput(temp));

   }

}
```

The rest renders the frame and starts the game loop.

This is my handler class. This class creates an objects list, and adds and removes objects when required.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class GameHandler {

    LinkedList<GameObjects> gameObjects = new LinkedList<GameObjects>();

    public void tick(){
        for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++){
            GameObjects temp = gameObjects.get(i);
            temp.tick();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++){
            GameObjects temp = gameObjects.get(i);
            temp.render(g);
        }
    }

    public void newObject(GameObjects object){

        this.gameObjects.add(object);

    }

    public void deleteObject(GameObjects object){

        this.gameObjects.remove(object);
    }
}
```

This is the MouseInput class: Where each object is sent to and has a MouseEvent. What I want here is that each object should have a different MouseEvent ID, so when it is clicked on it returns a unique ID for each object. However at this moment it returns the same value for all objects. I want to be able to select and object, by clicking on it, and then click on a new position and that object should move there.

```
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.util.LinkedList;


    public class MouseInput implements MouseListener {

            private GameHandler handler;
            private GameObjects object;

            public MouseInput(GameObjects Object){

            this.object = Object;


            }



            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {



                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                int b = e.getClickCount();

                int c = e.getID();

                /*NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE*/


                /*THIS JUST MOVES THE OBJECT WHERE I CLICK, BUT WHEN I HAVE MULTIPLE OBJECTS AND I CLICK, ONLY ONE OBJECT MOVES AND THE REST DISAPEAR*/
                    if(b == 2){
                        if(object.getID() == ID.playerOne ){

                            object.setX(x);
                            object.setY(y);
                        }
                    }



            }





            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        }
```

Apologies for all the code. I tried to post as little as possible.

Comment: **I tried to post as little as possible** !! This line hurted me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to add a mouslistener to each object so that they can each have their own MouseEvent.

```
for(int i = 0; i < handler.gameObjects.size(); i++)
{
    GameObjects temp = handler.gameObjects.get(i);
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseInput(temp));
}
```

That code is adding the MouseListener to the same object, not a different object. Instead I would guess the code should be:

```
//this.addMouseListener(new MouseInput(temp));
temp.addMouseListener(new MouseInput(temp));
```

> so when it is clicked on it returns a unique ID for each object.

If you want to know which object was clicked you can get that information from the MouseEvent:

```
GameObjects temp = (GameObjects)e.getSource();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, I finally figured it out and got it to work. Thank you again!